# Change state of a widget from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I have recently started working with flutter web. What is best practice to change state of a widget which is in one file (eg: Home.dart) from another file (eg: test.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color colo = Colors.black;

  testA() {
    setState(() {
      colo = Colors.blue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            color: colo,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                testA();
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Text("test"),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In above code, I have created a box with initial color black and changing it using a gesture detector which is in same class MyHomePage. How can I do the same using a different class in a different dart file.

HomePage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testweb/test.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color colo = Colors.black;

  testA() {
    setState(() {
      colo = Colors.blue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            color: colo,
          ),
          TestB()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

testB.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestBState createState() => _TestBState();
}

class _TestBState extends State<TestB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          testA();
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text("test"),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Function in TestB onTap to set color of container of HomePage.

TestB.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestB extends StatefulWidget {
 Function colorChange;
 TestB({this.colorChange});
  @override
  _TestBState createState() => _TestBState();
}

class _TestBState extends State<TestB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          widget.colorChange(Colors.blue);
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text("test"),
        ));
  }
}
```

Home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testweb/test.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color colo = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            color: colo,
          ),
          TestB(colorChange: (color){
           setState(() {
            colo = color;
           });
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

tell me if it works.